# How to make my API accesable for more than one user with JWT

Tags: spring-boot, api, authentication, jwt

I'm trying to create a custom backend with Spring Boot and Kotlin for my e-commerce app and as it is obvious I need an authentication mechanism for users. I tried to create that mechanism with generating and JWT and storing it in httpOnly cookie for each login. Although it worked for one user when a second or third user try to login and make requests then my api creates new token and only the latest user can make requests. How can i manage to create a multi-user authentication system ?

My User Controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
class UserController(
    private val userService: UserService
) {
    @ExceptionHandler(NoSuchElementException::class)
    fun handleNotFound(e: NoSuchElementException): ResponseEntity<String> =
        ResponseEntity(e.message, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)

    @ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException::class)
    fun handleBadRequest(e: IllegalArgumentException): ResponseEntity<String> =
        ResponseEntity(e.message, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)

    @PostMapping("register")
    fun register(@RequestBody body: RegisterDTO): ResponseEntity<User> {

        val user = User()
        user.name = body.name
        user.email = body.email
        user.password = body.password
        return ResponseEntity.ok(this.userService.save(user))
    }

    @PostMapping("login")
    fun login(@RequestBody body: LoginDTO, response: HttpServletResponse): ResponseEntity<Any> {

        val user = this.userService.findByEmail(body.email)
            ?: return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(Message("User not found"))

        if (!user.comparePasswords(body.password))
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(Message("Invalid password"))

        val issuer = user.id.toString()

        val jwt = Jwts.builder()
            .setIssuer(issuer)
            .setExpiration(Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 60 * 24 * 1000))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, "secret").compact()

        val cookie = Cookie("jwt", jwt)
        cookie.isHttpOnly = true //very IMPORTANT

        response.addCookie(cookie)

        return ResponseEntity.ok(Message("Succes"))
    }

    @GetMapping("user")
    fun user(@CookieValue("jwt") jwt: String?): ResponseEntity<Any> {
        try {

            if (jwt == null)
                return ResponseEntity.status(401).body("Not authenticated")
            val body = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("secret").parseClaimsJws(jwt).body
            return ResponseEntity.ok(this.userService.getById(body.issuer.toInt()))

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(401).body("Not authenticated")
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("logout")
    fun logout(response: HttpServletResponse): ResponseEntity<Any> {

        val cookie = Cookie("jwt", "")
        cookie.maxAge = 0

        response.addCookie(cookie)

        return ResponseEntity.ok("success to delete")
    }
}
```

And one example function from my dataController
It returns list of banks if jwt is not null :

```
    @GetMapping
    fun getBanks(@CookieValue jwt: String?): ResponseEntity<Any> {

        if (jwt == null)
            return ResponseEntity.status(401).body("Not authenticated")
        return ResponseEntity.ok(service.getBanks())
    }
```

Comment: every user will have different jwt as expected. so every user will use their own jwt to access other endpoints and if you want to test with other user's info, use each user's jwt..